# debugging tornado memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks, tornado

I built a cryptocurrency portfolio application using tornado and python. Tornado 4.4.2 and pypy Python 2.7.13 (84a2f3e6a7f8, Oct 03 2017, 11:00:55)
[PyPy 5.9.0 with GCC 6.2.0 20160901] in a virtual environment.

Until recently I had no memory issues with tornado.

I am using websocket with SockJSConnection objects to update the real time info on the site.

I changed nothing in the sockets code recently, but I did update some modules that are imported and I call functions from.

Suddenly the server was shutting down, checking the event logs I can see the operating system (Linux Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) was terminating the process because of memory.

I have noticed that even without web clients, memory just starts creeping upward. When there are clients getting data back (this is very data intensive app) it blows up the memory faster.

Using print statements I can see nothing happening while it is idle except that I have code running (which has never been changed)  to terminate connections with clients that have dropped out. I use the periodicCallback to check again in 60 seconds -

clients = [] # list of web clients maintaining open socket connections with server

def ScheduleSocketCleaning():

```
print "Started ScheduleSocketCleaning()"

def cleanSocketHouse():
    n = pendulum.now(tz='America/New_York').to_datetime_string()
    print "checking sockets @ %s"%n
    if clients:
        for x in clients:
            print "found client "+ x.id + " "+x.ipaddress +" "+x.is_closed
        clients[:] = [y for y in clients if not y.is_closed]
    else: print "no clients at this time"

loop = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(cleanSocketHouse, 60000,
                                       io_loop=tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance())
loop.start()
```

This code is started as launch.

My question is how can I debug this kind of problem. The server had been stable for many months.  I have looked at all new code (which is in modules) for possible answers, but these functions are not called with no clients.

Clearly I have done something to cause this problem -- but I am unsure as to how to debug.

Thanks for any help